# MVC 3 AJAX Form Posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

All,

I am trying to implement an AJAX post of a form.(New to ASP.NET MVC,coming from a Rails background)

When I submit the form and watch the FireBug console as well as the page, the form is not doing an AJAX post. The AJAX handler gets invoked (Contact/Process) and the form redirects there, to Contact/Process showing just the response message, instead of updating the designated div on the form

I must be implementing something wrong some place, most likely in the controller that handles the AJAX POST. Not sure what else.

Thanks

**The Form (/Views/Contact/Create.cshtml)**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="content">
    <div id="Status"></div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Process","Contact", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Status"}))
    {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

         <p><span class="required">&#42; All fields are required.</span></p>

        <!-- First Name -->
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.FirstName) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Contact.FirstName)


        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/> 
       </div>

    }

</div>
```

**The Controller Action (/Controllers/ContactController.cs)**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string Process(ContactViewModel c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            c.Contact.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            db.Contacts.Add(c.Contact);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Success!";

        }

        return "Failure";

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these two libraries:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Update**

Your Process action needs to return an `ActionResult` and use `Content` rather than a string.

Change it to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(ContactViewModel c)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        c.Contact.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        db.Contacts.Add(c.Contact);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Content("Success!");

    }

    return Content("Failure");

}
```

Comment: Good catch on the full jquery library as well as the unobtrusive one.

Comment: You can also add a loading element in your ajax options by adding LoadingElementId="loading". :)

Comment: hmm. still not working - do i need to intercept the submit button click?

Comment: No, you should be ok. Will have a check locally 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

You need add jquery script to page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That's always a pain. My first MVC project was months of work. When I started my second project, I was pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working. ^^This was the reason why.

Comment: Give you an upvote as it was one of the problems that I listed too. :)